# How to find an intersection among several columns of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, intersection

Suppose I have 5 columns, C1,..., C5 defined as:

```
df<-(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)

C1 =("Groucho", "John", "Adam", "Mouse", "Harpo", "Zeppo") 
C2 = ("Tom", "William", "Robert", "Julie", "Smith", "Groucho", "Harpo", "Zeppo") 
C3 = ("Harpo", "Groucho", "Jerry", "Duck", "Mickey", "Harpo", "Zeppo")
C4 = ("Seth", "Zeppo", "Groucho", "Harpo")
C5 = ("Groucho", "Harpo", "Zeppo", "Sam")
```

I am using R and I would like to find the intersection among these five columns (I know they were written in horizontal, like rows, but they are columns). I could not find a similar question here and the "intersect" command only works with two columns.

Any tip?

Comment: Do you mean `Reduce(intersect, df)`?

Comment: yes. thanks a lot.